# The disadvantages of JavaScript prototype inheritance, what are they?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

I recently watched [Douglas Crockford's JavaScript presentations](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/02/03/video-crockonjs-1/), where he raves about JavaScript prototype inheritance as if it is  the best thing since sliced white bread.  Considering Crockford's reputation, it may very well be.

Can someone please tell me what is the downside of JavaScript prototype inheritance? (compared to class inheritance in C# or Java, for example)

Comment: Don't include that it induces headeaches in developers who have been programming for years with class inheritance.  That one is obvious :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things I miss when sub-classing an existing object in Javascript vs. inheriting from a class in C++:

1. No standard (built-into-the-language) way of writing it that looks the same no matter which developer wrote it.
2. Writing your code doesn't naturally produce an interface definition the way the class header file does in C++.
3. There's no standard way to do protected and private member variables or methods.  There are some conventions for some things, but again different developers do it differently.
4. There's no compiler step to tell you when you've made foolish typing mistakes in your definition.
5. There's no type-safety when you want it.

Don't get me wrong, there are a zillion advantages to the way javascript prototype inheritance works vs C++, but these are some of the places where I find javascript works less smoothly.

4 and 5 are not strictly related to prototype inheritance, but they come into play when you have a significant sized project with many modules, many classes and lots of files and you wish to refactor some classes.  In C++, you can change the classes, change as many callers as you can find and then let the compiler find all the remaining references for you that need fixing.  If you've added parameters, changed types, changed method names, moved methods,etc... the compiler will show you were you need to fix things.

In Javascript, there is no easy way to discover all possible pieces of code that need to be changed without literally executing every possible code path to see if you've missed something or made some typo.  While this is a general disadvantage of javascript, I've found it particularly comes into play when refactoring existing classes in a significant-sized project.  I've come near the end of a release cycle in a significant-sized JS project and decided that I should NOT do any refactoring to fix a problem (even though that was the better solution) because the risk of not finding all possible ramifications of that change was much higher in JS than C++.

So, consequently, I find it's riskier to make some types of OO-related changes in a JS project.

Comment: I *do not* miss having to "declare" my functions before I implement them in C++

Comment: Those sound more like general disadvantages of JS instead of those pertaining to Prototype inheritance.

Comment: 4 and 5 are about JavaScript having dynamic typing, not about prototyping.

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies - I didn't say I miss having to "declare" my functions before I implement them.  But, I do miss having a naturally self documenting interface that everyone does the same for a class.  Maybe not a big deal in a small, one-person project.  A much bigger deal in a larger or multi-person project.

Comment: @Matt and @Jakob.  I've added additional info to my answer that explains why I think 4 and 5 are relevant to the question.

Comment: ' they come into play when you have a significant sized project with many modules, many classes and lots of files and you wish to refactor some classes. ' IMO this is what proponents of JS's prototypical inheritance always overlook - in the real world, it's way easier to write a pile of unwieldy spaghetti.

Comment: @siliconrockstar - Uh, that issue has NOTHING to do with prototypical inheritance.  That has to do with the fact that the language is not compiled or typed.  If one wants those features, you can use TypeScript which adds type checking on top of Javascript (and still has prototypical inheritance).  In addition, since this answer was written in 2011, Javascript has added formal syntax for subclassing too.  And, I've seen some pretty horrible unwieldy spaghetti in C++ too.  In many ways, it offers even more rope that one can hang themselves with.

Comment: ^ that's simply untrue but explaining it to you isn't my job, so 'ok'.

Comment: @siliconrockstar - I understand the issues you're talking about and they are real with Javascript, but it isn't prototypical inheritance that causes them.  That's my point.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, a significant disadvantage is that you can't mimic Java's "private" member variables by encapsulating a variable within a closure, but still have it accessible to methods subsequently added to the prototype.

i.e.:

```
function MyObject() {
    var foo = 1;
    this.bar = 2;
}

MyObject.prototype.getFoo = function() {
    // can't access "foo" here!
}

MyObject.prototype.getBar = function() {
    return this.bar; // OK!
}
```

This confuses OO programmers who are taught to make member variables private.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that JavaScript lacks an analogue of the `protected` keyword.

Comment: @Rice no, it's more than that - functions in the prototype can't access _their own_ "private" variables, let alone anything in a base class.

Comment: This has tripped me up a couple of times - I have functions that are not prototype, but instead instance based, because of this, and that's the only reason.  Though, arguably, I'm not sure I want closures accessible like that, but some other form of encapsulation would be nice.

Comment: @Matt yes, that's what I do to, but only in classes where I only expect to create a few instances.

Comment: @Alnitak : sure you can! if you declare the "private" vars into the prototype object:  `MyObject.prototype = new function(){var private = "private";this.getPrivate = function(){return private;}}` it is a bit complicated, but it can be done

Comment: @gion_13 What you are creating there is a private **static** variable, that variable is shared among all the other instance of MyObject. The only way to have true private instance variable is through functional OOP, which doesn't use prototype.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main danger is that multiple parties can override one another's prototype methods, leading to unexpected behavior.

This is particularly dangerous *because* so many programmers get excited about prototype "inheritance" (I'd call it *extension*) and therefore start using it all over the place, adding methods left and right that may have ambiguous or subjective behavior. Ultimately, if left unchecked, this kind of "prototype method proliferation" can lead to very difficult-to-maintain code.

A popular example would be the `trim` method. It might be implemented something like this by one party:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    // remove all ' ' characters from left & right
}
```

Then another party might create a *new* definition, with a **completely different signature**, taking an argument which specifies the character to trim. Suddenly all the code that passes nothing to `trim` has no effect.

Or another party reimplements the method to strip `' '` characters *and* other forms of white space (e.g., tabs, line breaks). This might go unnoticed for some time but lead to odd behavior down the road.

Depending on the project, these may be considered remote dangers. But they can happen, and from my understanding this is why libraries such as [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) opt to keep all their methods within namespaces rather than add prototype methods.

(**Update**: Obviously, this is a judgment call. *Other* libraries--namely, the aptly-named [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)--*do* go the prototype route. I'm not trying to say one way is right or wrong, only that this is the argument I've heard against using prototype methods too liberally.)

Comment: While a factually correct answer, it's more of a disadvantage for modifying the prototype of built-in objects, not necessarily a disadvantage to the prototype method itself.

Comment: @Zikes: Well, certainly it's most relevant for built-in objects. But I think even the topic the OP is asking about (using the prototype method as an inheritance mechanism) is susceptible to the same issue, though with a much smaller probability. To be honest, I *like* the prototype method myself; this is just my understanding of why some believe it should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

I miss being able to separate interface from implementation. In languages with an inheritance system that includes concepts like `abstract` or `interface`, you could e.g. declare your interface in your domain layer but put the implementation in your infrastructure layer. (Cf. [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).)  JavaScript's inheritance system has no way to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know if my intuitive answer matches up with what the experts think.

What concerns me is that if I have a function in C# (for the sake of discussion) that takes a parameter, any developer who writes code that calls my function immediately knows from the function signature what sort of parameters it takes and what type of value it returns.

With JavaScript "duck-typing", someone could inherit one of my objects and change its member functions and values (Yes, I know that functions are values in JavaScript) in almost any way imaginable so that the object they pass in to my function bears no resemblance to the object I expect my function to be passed.

I feel like there is no good way to make it obvious how a function is supposed to be called.

Comment: But that's about Javascript's weak typing, not about prototype extension, which was what the question related to .

Comment: Part of being treated like an adult (ie: not being forced into some protect-you-from-yourself model like Java's) is that in order for stuff to work, you have to *act* like an adult. Typewise, that means making your duckalikes act like ducks.  If you randomly change how `quack()` is called, what you have isn't a duck anymore.  And the person who changed it obviously broke duckability.  The fault lies with them, not with the model.

Comment: As for it being obvious how to call a function:  in Chrome, FF, IE, and node, at least, `someFunction.toString()` will give you a stringified definition for the function -- that is, it will show you the args, and even the code (as long as you're getting a JS function and not a native-code one).  I'm pretty sure that's standard.  So there's no real excuse for not knowing how it should be called.